# Change ESX Server 3 iSCSI IP Addresses

Tags: vmware-esx, iscsi, ip-address

Moved ESX farm to a different datacenter with a different IP address scheme.

Two questions:
1) I've changed the ip address of the service console but when I boot it still says: "You can manage this host from the web at http://OLD-IP-ADDRESS" - how do I fix that?

2) Nothing has changed with the iSCSI host 'cept for the IP addresses. How can I easily change the IP addresses of the iSCSI targets in the ESX host (I've already changed it on the iSCSI server).

-- It currently has to be done via the console since I can't get to the web or VirtualCenter. This is ESX Server 3.0.3

Thanks!!

Comment: Yep it is s/w iSCSI. Attempting some tricks now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the iSCSI address change is concerned if you have changed the ip-address of the vmkernel port you are using for iSCSI then for ESX 3.5 you will have to reboot the ESX host otherwise things will get unstable. That's if the change refers to the iSCSI Software initiator on the ESX Server. If that hasn't changed and you just want to change the iSCSI target address the initiator is pointing to then just change the properties in the initiator [Config Tab, Storage Adaptors, iSCSI Software Initiator, Dynamic Discovery, Add Send Targets Server] to point to the new iSCSI target address. Again a reboot is strongly recommended, the ESX 3.5 Software initiator does not like changes. If you use iqn's for access control on the iSCSI target changes like these are simpler since you don't need to modify the ACL's when changing the initiator ip-addresses provided that works with your iSCSI target of course.

I'm not sure about your first question, I've never paid attention to that message on an ESX console after I've changed an SC address. Two questions - [1] does the new address work for web management? [2] Did you re-create\directly modify vswif0 when changing the SC address or did you just add a new SC port and disable vswif0?.

Comment: Doesn't work via the web and i did destroy/re-create vswif0. This is also ESX3.0 and not 3.5 (my bad)

Comment: Is your VLAN Setup correct? Can you ping from the ESX HOst to your Network?

Comment: Was able to get VirtualCenter talking to the hosts, made the changes above, and now I have my iSCSI devices. Thanks!!

Comment: Out of curiosity - what did you do to get VirtualCenter talking to the host again?

Comment: After fixing the /etc/hosts file and restarting the box I was able to fire up Virtual Infrastructure client to manipulate the server. :D

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to use the command vmkiscsi-tool and esxcfg-rescan
I'm assuming software iSCSI - if it's hardware replace vmhba32 references w/ your HBA identifier

you would do 
`vmkiscsi-tool -D -a <iSCSI IP> vmhba32` then `vmkiscsi-tool -T -l vmhba32` to list the found targets then you can do an `esxcfrg-rescan vmbha32` to rescan the targets

As far as your screen showing the old ip address, check your /etc/hosts file you probably have the old ip in there.